pure_funcs does not work in terser-webpack-plugin
I have a log function that is used everywhere in my code with this pattern:
const log = anylogger('x.y')
...
log('information...')

and the terse plugin configuration is like below:
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        compress: {
                            pure_funcs: ['log'], //only work thru. webpack dev server
                            drop_console: true
                        }
                    }
                })

I find that the terse plugin works on pure_funcs to have all log(..) calls trimmed when pages are accessed through webpack-dev server. However pure_funcs does not work (but drop_console work) when webpack build the code.
